# Oracle 6i reports engine crash on Windows server 2008r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, oracle

**Background**:
We have Oracle 6i applications that used to run on Windows server 2003.
We've migrated to 2008r2, and we managed to get these applications running almost perfectly (took a while and a lot of ProcMon logs...).
I know it's not supported, etc. but I don't see management agreeing for an upgrade - they would rather stay with 2003...

**What the application does**:
The application collects data, and then creates emails (like mailto) with an address and an attached file (rtf).

**Now we are stuck with the following problem**:
The problem is that, quite randomly, the process RWRBE60.exe crashes before Outlook even starts.
I've disabled all Outlook security features, but it didn't help (for that particular problem anyway).
In the event viewer it shows the faulty module, but it looks random too (e.g. dhcpcsvc.dll, dhcpcsvc6.dll, olmapi32.dll...).
All tests were done on the same server, with the same user, the same application and the same configurations.

**A few more weird things found in ProcMon**:
1. It loads many (maybe even all of them) dlls from Windows and System32 (like dhcpcsvc.dll - I mean, WTH?!)
2. I saw once that it loaded a dll named OMSXP32.DLL, which didn't exist when I checked later.
3. When it works it seem to do less searching for the dlls it needs.

Any suggestion or a lead is welcome.

Comment: `I know it's not supported` - Well, what are your options? Keep hitting it with a hammer in the hopes that you can get it to work, with varying degrees of success, or not, or put it on a supported platform.

Comment: @joeqwerty I have to hammered at it long enough, so I'm trying to get a fresh perspective. I just trying to deplete all my options, because If I give up, it means we have a security problem (Server 2003) that we can't solve, and as I wrote, management ain't gonna upgrade the damn software. We already got hit by a Ransomware that was downloaded on server 2003 without the user's knowledge from a compromised legitimate site (though we were prepared, and recovery perfectly).